# Reference for the formal definition of sigma protocol

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm looking for a book that contains the formal definition of sigma protocol (something like: *A sigma protocol for a relation $R$ and a challenge space $C$ is... that satisfies the properties of soundness..., completeness..., honest verifier zero-knowledge...*)

I keep finding books that gives an *example* of sigma protocol, and they somehow discuss the main properties, but what I would like is a reference with an abstract definition.

I need it for a course for students of mathematics, who are used to read the formal definition of objects.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://webee.technion.ac.il/~hugo/sigma.html)?